# Memory addresses for literals

Tags: python

How does Python assign memory addresses for literals?

```
>>> id(1)
4298171352
>>> id(2)
4298171328
>>> id(1.0019)
4299162496
>>> id(1.0025)
4299162496
>>> id(1.00999)
4299162496
>>> a = 1.0025
>>> b = 1.00999
>>> id(a)
4299162496
>>> id(b)
4299162472
>>> 
jg@jg ~ $ python
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (x86_64)| (default, May 28 2015, 17:04:42) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> id(1)
4298171352
```

How is it that 1.0025 and 1.0999 correspond to the same memory location, but when I set a and b equal to those respective values there are now different memory locations?  How is it that when I restart Python, the memory address for 1 is the same?

Also, does this mean that there is a pre-existing memory address for every integer and binned floats and character?

Comment: Since you're not assigning the values anywhere, it can reuse the memory.

Comment: Python caches small integers (I don't remember the exact range at the moment) and since the caching is done at startup, It seems reasonable that they'd have the same memory address from one run to the next -- but I'm no expert on how the python memory allocator works (and how it interacts with the OS's memory allocator).

Comment: See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/306313/748858

Comment: Python 2 and 3 handle integers very differently so please tag a version in your question as it is already quite broad. There is a good discussion of [the Python 2 integer implementation](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-integer-objects-implementation/) on Laurent Luce's blog.

Comment: Funnily enough I can only get the same id after restarting the interpreter using python3.4, python2.7.6 always gives me a new id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id):

> Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same `id()` value.

Since you're not assigning `1.0025` and `1.0999` to anything in your first test, each value's lifetime end as soon as it finishes executing the statement that prints its `id()`. Since their lifetimes don't overlap, Python can reuse the same memory for them, so they get the same `id()` values.

When you do assign them to variables, their lifetimes exist as long as those variables hold the values. As a result, they can't be put in the same memory, and `id()` returns different values.

Comment: I think the OP is more referring to restarting the interpreter and getting the same id

Comment: I think he's just asking why he gets the same ID when he types it into the interactive command loop.

Comment: Looking at it again I think he/she is asking both. I cannot reproduce the same id using python2.7.6 each time I restart an interpreter but with python3.4 I can